# Grid View data and selected index not in sync

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a C# ASP.NET application with the main screen being a Grid View as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblTasks" Height="50px" Width="100%" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" gridlines="None" emptyDataText="No Records Found" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" runat="server" OnRowCreated="tblTasks_RowCreated" OnRowEditing="tblTasks_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Who Took Call" HeaderText="Who Took Call" ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date Entered" HeaderText="Date Entered" ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date Entered" HeaderText="Date Entered"  ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Dispatched To" HeaderText="Dispatched To"  ItemStyle-CssClass="datacol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headingcol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Resolution" HeaderText="Resolution" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date Completed" HeaderText="Date Completed" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I then populate the grid view via a stored procedure on page load as such:

```
myGridView grid = new myGridView(tblTasks, "p_select_all_tasks");
```

Which passes to this class/method:

```
public myGridView(GridView argGrid, string argStoredProcedure)
    {
        this.dataGrid = argGrid;
        this.storedProcedure = argStoredProcedure;
        this.connection = GeneralUtility.getConnectionString();
        fill();
    }

    public myGridView(GridView argGrid, string argStoredProcedure, List<SqlParameter> argParamter)
    {
        this.dataGrid = argGrid;
        this.storedProcedure = argStoredProcedure;
        this.connection = GeneralUtility.getConnectionString();
        this.parameter = argParamter;
        fill();
    }

    private void fill()
    {
        using (myDatabase db = new myDatabase(connection))
        {
            this.dataGrid.DataSource = null;
            this.dataGrid.DataSource = db.ExecuteCommandWithDSReturn(storedProcedure, parameter);
            this.dataGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Now at the top of the main page there are some drop downs the user can select values from and click an update button to change the values in the Grid View displayed using this code:

```
protected void btn_Click_Return_Tasks(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userToFetchTasksFor = userSelectionDropDown.SelectedValue;
        String statusToFetchTasksFor = statusSelectionDropDown.SelectedValue;

        if (!userToFetchTasksFor.Equals("All") && !statusToFetchTasksFor.Equals("All"))
        {
            List<SqlParameter> tmpParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            tmpParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@user_name", userToFetchTasksFor));
            tmpParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", statusToFetchTasksFor));
            myGridView grid = new myGridView(tblTasks, "p_select_task_by_user_name_and_status", tmpParams);             
        }
        else if (userToFetchTasksFor.Equals("All") && !statusToFetchTasksFor.Equals("All"))
        {
            List<SqlParameter> tmpParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            tmpParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", statusToFetchTasksFor));
            myGridView grid = new myGridView(tblTasks, "p_select_task_by_status", tmpParams);
        }
        else if (!userToFetchTasksFor.Equals("All") && statusToFetchTasksFor.Equals("All"))
        {
            List<SqlParameter> tmpParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            tmpParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@user_name", userToFetchTasksFor));
            myGridView grid = new myGridView(tblTasks, "p_select_task_by_user_name", tmpParams);
        }
        else
        {
            myGridView grid = new myGridView(tblTasks, "p_select_all_tasks");
        }
    }
```

The grid view repopulates fine and displays correct information. Now to the problem. When I first load in the full grid view on page load I can click the edit button and it runs this code:

```
protected void tblTasks_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

        DataSet ds = (DataSet)gv.DataSource;

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        string s = string.Empty;

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            String column = dc.ToString();
            if (dc.ToString().Equals("ID"))
            {
                nvc.Add(dc.ColumnName, tblTasks.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
                //String p = tblTasks.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            }
        }
        var array = (from key in nvc.AllKeys
                     from value in nvc.GetValues(key)
                     select string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))).ToArray();

        Response.Redirect(@"/EditTask.aspx?" + string.Join("&", array));
    }
```

This works great that first load but after I refresh my grid view via the btn_Click_Return_Tasks command the indexes are out of sync with the data in the grid view. The slected index is correct but the tblTasks.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString() value pulls from what the table was when the page first loaded and not what the actual row is now after update. How can I fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't call the database everytime the user clicks a dropdown, try filtering the data instead. call the database once to get the  dataset you want to use for the grid.

Comment: The db only gets called when the user clicks the "Update" button next to the drop downs. The update then grabs the drop down's selected values and sets them as stored procedure params an executes that.